# Problem with the driver option

Tags: output-driver

After successfully typesetting my file Book3_new many times, with a fairly extensive bibliography, I have started to add an index, using `\usepackage{makeidx}`
and `\makeindex`.  This worked well for a while, but when the index had developed to a certain point, I got the following error message.

```
! Package hyperref Error: Wrong DVI mode driver option `dvips',
(hyperref)                because pdfTeX or LuaTeX is running in PDF mode.
```

If I hit return the typesetting continues, but generates another error message as follows:

```
(./Header_new.tex) (./Book3_new.aux
! Undefined control sequence.
l.252 \bibcit
```

Here Book3_new is the name of the rather large file (just over 10000 lines).
`Book3_new.aux` does contain many lines that begin `\bibcite`; but the file
has not been completed, and the last line (line 252, as in the error message) ends `\bibcit`

Comment: Well do you use the `dvips` option? If you do, don't.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @JuriRobl, AFAIU OP's problem is that somehow `makeidx` is injecting this. Perhaps it needs some nudgning in direction PDF?

Comment: @vonbrand According to his other question he loads `hyperref` with `dvips`.

Comment: Has this been resolved? If not, please edit your question and add a short example code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I have voted to close this question because it cannot be answered in its current form (no MWE).